# Avoid inheriting of parent's css effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have `<div class="jumbotron text-center"><nav>something</nav></div>` this line of code and the `jumbotron` has some CSS effects something like

```
.jumbotron{
    background: url("image-url") no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 78vh;
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

but all I want is **only** the jumbotron's background image gets the CSS effects, not the `nav` tag. currently, the `nav` tag inherits the`filter: brigtness (50%)`, is there anyway **only** the background-image gets the effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. A `filter` will affect current element with all its contents (including children).

Therefore the way to go here is to move `<nav>` outside of `.jumbotron`, wrap them in a common relative parent and render `<nav>` above `.jumbotron`.
Proof of concept:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
.relative > .absolute {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  /* making it visible */
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.jumbotron{
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/1024/540") no-repeat center center /cover; 
  height: 78vh;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="jumbotron"></div>
  <nav class="absolute">something</nav>
</div>
```

Feel free to rename the classes and adjust to your particular needs.